# How will the transition to RingCT work?

Tags: ringct, hard-fork

When Monero implements RingCT, how will the transition be handled?

In particular, how will pre RingCT outputs be migrated into outputs available for use in RingCT transactions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When someone uses a rct transaction, the outputs are necessarily rct. From hard fork 4 (expected in or around march 2017), both rct and non rct transactions will be permitted. From hard fork 5 (expected in or around september 2017), non rct transasctions will be permitted only if they are spending unmixable outputs (ie, the rules for allowing mixin 0 now).

If you want to make all your outputs rct, you should be able to use `sweep_unmixable` first, then `sweep_all`. Assuming you do not have a large amount of tiny inputs, that should make your whole balance only in rct outputs.

Comment: The content of the answer above it perfect, but I wanted to mention that there now appears to be a good chance the timetables able will be accelerated: https://hellomonero.com/article/monero-bi-weekly-dev-meeting-note-highlights-2016-08-28

Comment: Update: Hard fork v4 (RingCT allowed, not necessary) was Jan 2017, and Hard fork v5 (RingCT mandatory) was Sept 15 2017 ("increased the minimum ring signature size to 5 across the network, banned duplicate ring members in a ring signature, and enforced the use of ringCT for all transaction outputs").